# To what degree have Calabi-Yau manifolds been shown to be all linked by conifold transitions?

Tags: differential-geometry, string-theory, topology, calabi-yau

Originally, the number of Calabi-Yau manifolds (these are special vacuum solutions of Einsteins GR) was estimated by Yau to be a small finite number, later he revised it to be a large finite number - possibly tens of thousands. However, Reid suggests the number might be infinite. However, he has also suggested that they are all connected by a mild generalisation of conifolds.

These topology changing conifold transitions are important in string theory where they lead to completely smooth physics, even though they, thrmselces, are singular.

**Q. What progress has there been made towards Reids conjecture?**